# Simplifying the expression using Boolean Algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

Simplifying the expression using Boolean Algebra into sum-of-products (SOP) expressions
. refers to AND
+ refers to OR

(y' + x) ∙ (z + z') ∙ (y' + x') + (z + x'∙z) ∙ (x + y)

This is what I have so far.

(y' + x) ∙ (z + z') ∙ (y' + x') + (z + x'∙z) ∙ (x + y)

= (y' + x) ∙ 1 ∙ (y' + x') + (z + x'∙z) ∙ (x + y) (Using Complement Element, x+x' = 1)

= (y' + x) ∙ (y' + x') + (z + x'∙z) ∙ (x + y) (Using Identity Element, 1 . x = x . 1 = x)

**Updated with new question**

( (a + b) ∙ (a' + c') )' + (b + c')' + a∙b'∙c

= ( (a + b) ∙ (a' + c') )' + (b' . c) + a∙b'∙c

= (( a ∙ (a' + c') + b ∙ (a' + c') )' + (b' . c) + a∙b'∙c

= (( a ∙ a' + a ∙ c') + (a' . b + b ∙ c') )' + (b' . c) + a∙b'∙c

= (( a ∙ c') + (a' . b  + b ∙ c') )' + (b' . c) + a∙b'∙c

= ( a ∙ c')' . (a'. b + b ∙ c')'  + (b' . c) + a∙b'∙c

= ( a' + c) . (a + b' ∙ b' + c)  + (b' . c) + a∙b'∙c

I am stuck here.
How do I continue?
Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a start:

$$\begin{align*}
(y'+x)\cdot(y'+x')&=y'\cdot(y'+x')+x\cdot(y'+x')\\
&=y'\cdot y'+y'\cdot x'+x\cdot y'+x\cdot x'\\
&=y'+x'\cdot y'+x\cdot y'\\
&=y'+(x'+x)\cdot y'\\
&=y'+y'\\
&=y'
\end{align*}$$

Note also that $z+x'\cdot z=(1+x')\cdot z=z$.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply! :)
I shall go and try now. :)

Comment: @Lawrence: You’re welcome; good luck with it!

Comment: Hi again,
I worked out the whole thing and I got y' + z * (x+y)
Can it be simplify further?

Comment: @Lawrence: Not really, though $y'+x\cdot z+y\cdot z$ might be considered simpler in many contexts, because it’s in [disjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form).

Comment: Hi again, I need help with a new question.
Please take a look. :)

Comment: @Lawrence: Would you do me a favor and make it a separate question? This is getting a bit crowded.

Comment: Here is the link to the new question.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293429/simplifying-the-expression-using-boolean-algebra-part-2

Comment: @Lawrence: Got it; I’ll take a look.